# In Javascript, once I randomly get values from an array, how can I rerun the function to get new values?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, loops, replace

I have a function that creates a table and selects three random values from an array to fill the table(see code).

---

**Problem:** Instead of choosing three new values, the function simply adds to the bottom and creates a bigger table.

---

**Goal:** Create function so that I can get 3 random array elements, and then rerun a function that selects 3 new elements to replace the 3 old elements!

---

HTML

```
<table border="1" id = 'hi'>
    <tr>

        <th id = 'replace' onclick="getTable(); myFunction();">Find Workout</th>

</table>
```

---

JS

```
var workouts = ['situps', 'planks', 'hollow rock', 'bicycle', 'L2S']

//Setting a copy of the array to be manipulated
var copy = workouts.slice();

//Prepping the table before the loop so it can be filled in with values
var table = '';

for(var j = 0; j < 3; j++)
{
//Setting a variable to be a random integer between 1 and 3, then 
saving that in a new variable.
//That new variable, answer, plugs the value received into the array to 
get one of the indexes of the array 
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * copy.length);
    var answer = copy[random]; 

    table += '<tr>';
    table += '<td>';
    table += answer;
    table += '</td>';
    table += '</tr>';

//Removing the selected item so it wont show again

    copy.splice(random, 1);
}

//Runs the function to create the table
function getTable() {
  document.getElementById('hi').innerHTML += ('<table border = 1>' + 
table + '</table>');
}

//Replace "Find Workout" with "Recycle" indicating you can recycle to 
get different workouts
function myFunction() {
  var str = document.getElementById('replace').innerHTML; 
  var res = str.replace("Find Workout", "Recycle");
  document.getElementById("replace").innerHTML = res;
}
```

Sorry if the code is a little long, I just wanted whoever reads this to know exactly what I am doing. I am sure some of the code isnt relevant.

Comment: Try changing you "+=" to "=" in your getTable() function. You're appending onto the end by using "+=".

Comment: Yep that did the trick! You rock, thanks a ton. Do you mind explaining the difference for me though? I want to understand it all so I can be better for bigger projects.

Comment: Yeah sure, the difference is that when you use =, it will essentially replacing everything within it as your setting a new value. += is used to add on to a value. If you want to add more rows on to a table for example using +=, however, I would recommend using .appendChild() and pass the element. I hope this makes sense, not the best at explaining :)